# Expose a public enum of an inner class from a wrapper class

Tags: c++, oop, enums, inner-classes

I have a situation like this:

```
class Inner
{
public:
    enum myEnum;
    myEnum getInnerEnumValue();
};

class Outer
{
private:
    Inner myInner;
public
    Inner::myEnum getOuterEnumValue()
    {
        return myInner.getInnerEnumValue();
    }
};
```

The Inner class is a pretty low-level wrapper around a hardware API, and the Outer class is an extra layer to provide nicer interfaces to some functionality and translate between different data structures.  I want the outside world to use Outer and forget about Inner.

However, Inner defines an enum and a getter method that's exactly what I need to get a certain piece of info.  I'd like to use this enum as a return type from Outer, just passing it straight through.  But if I declare the `getEnumValue()` function as shown above, I break encapsulation by making the outside world include the header file for Inner.

How can I lift the enum definition from Inner, without rewriting identical code, and present it as a public enum of Outer?

Comment: Perhaps the Pointer to Implementation Idiom might help? See http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C++_Programming/Idioms#Pointer_To_Implementation_.28pImpl.29

Answer (score 2):

I suggest simply providing a typedef in your outer class.  Something like:

```
class Outer {
public:
    typedef Inner::myEnum myEnum;

    myEnum getInnerEnumValue();
};
```

Or alternatively, you could use private inheritence (this might work a bit better):

```
class Outer : private Inner {
public:
    using Inner::myEnum;

    myEnum getInnerEnumValue();
};
```

At least this way, consumers of your class won't *directly* depend on the Inner class.  You'd be free to replace the typedef with your own enumeration in the future (if necessary).  Consumers will still have to include the Inner class header file, but there's no way around this.

Answer (score 0):

Move the enum out of `class Inner` into a new header file (maybe even seperate namespace)

**EDIT**

Since you want to preserve the interface of Inner (if I understand correctly), then add a pure base class for it, and define enum there.

Comment: But I still want that enum to be a part of Inner, for example if I decide to write a different wrapper later, I just want to include inner.h and not something else.

Comment: Ok, then you need a common base class for Inner classes. see edit